# Define cost function to maintain an autonomous vehicle in a particular area

Tags: geometry, optimization, control-theory, convex-geometry

Please I am looking for ideas on how to solve a problem.

I have an autonomous vehicle that can move on its own. I am trying to set up an optimization algorithm with a cost function that will ensure that the vehicle does not leave a particular geographical area or it should go back to the predefined area if it leaves. For example, If I deploy the vehicle in London, It should remain in London.

I wanted a convex, continuous, and twice differentiable cost function to guarantee the stability requirement of my algorithm.

So far, I have been trying to minimize the distance between the vehicle's current position and the desired position. But it is difficult to achieve. My cost function is shown below.

$$ y = (x_{latitude} - D_{latitude})^2 + (x_{longitude} - D_{longitude})^2 $$

$x_{latitude}$ and $x_{longitude}$ are the current position vehicle current position.

This cost function, will steer the vehicle to a point: namely $D_{longitude}$ and $D_{latitude}$. This requirement is too restrictive.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: This lacks context. You ask for something that is compatible with your algorithm but you do not mention what this algorithms really does. You mention that the last requirement is too restrictive, why is that? Why is it difficult to minimize the distance between the vehicle's current position and the desired position? What is the problem? Also, your vehicle must have some dynamics? What is it? You need to provide more details and context.

Comment: @KBS thanks for the comment. I may have used the wrong words when i said it is too restrictive. It is not practically possible to drive the vehicle to a particular point. At best, the vehicle can get very close to the point for a few minutes. Hence, It makes practical sense to maintain the vehicle in a polygonal region. The vehicle dynamics are unknown and it depends on other factors beyond our control. The simplest example I can think of is a hot air balloon where the dynamics depend on the wind velocity.

Comment: You will have to improve your question to include all  the necessary details to make your question clearer. It is too vague at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a cost function, why not impose constraints?  For example, you can enforce that the vehicle stay within a rectangular region by imposing bounds
$$\ell_\text{latitude} \le x_\text{latitude} \le u_\text{latitude} \\
\ell_\text{longitude} \le x_\text{longitude} \le u_\text{longitude}$$
More generally, you can impose linear constraints to restrict the vehicle to a polygonal region.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This may actually work. I am using an unconstrained optimization algorithm. So, I may need to figure out how to implement this.

Comment: If your algorithm does not support constraints, you can instead penalize their violation and include the penalty in the cost function.